# GSL Eigen Value Code

Tags: c, gsl, eigenvalue

I am working with GSL right now. I am facing some problem in finding Eigenvalues. It seems that GSL is not properly giving eigenvalues in case of symmetric matrices. I gave the input of certain symmetric matrices that ought to have 0 as an eigenvalue, however, non-zero Eigenvalues were what were returned by GSL's function to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a given symmetric matrix. Where might I be going wrong?

Comment: What is the exact value returned? If it's something like `1.7138541e-7`, then it's probably due to rounding error. Maybe post some code?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the GSL manual "The computed eigenvalues are accurate to an absolute accuracy of \epsilon ||A||_2, where \epsilon is the machine precision." If you could post more details I would be happy to investigate.